# Date output from table to CSV file

Tags: javascript, excel

Having a problem to output date from table row. So basically I have a table with data selected from PHP. I try to output the table data to Excel using JavaScript (found it through website). All of the data in Excel are looking good except for date that output "######".

So basically this is my table:
[image: So basically this is my table]

This is my JavaScript

```
<script>
         
function exportData(){
    /* Get the HTML data using Element by Id */
    var table = document.getElementById("report");
 
    /* Declaring array variable */
    var rows =[];
 
      //iterate through rows of table
    for(var i=0,row; row = table.rows[i];i++){
        //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
        //Get each cell value/column from the row
        column1 = row.cells[0].innerText;
        column2 = row.cells[1].innerText;
        column3 = row.cells[2].innerText;
        column4 = row.cells[3].innerText;
        column5 = row.cells[4].innerText;
        column6 = row.cells[5].innerText;
        column7 = row.cells[6].innerText;
        column8 = row.cells[7].innerText;
 
    /* add a new records in the array */
        rows.push(
            [
                column1,
                column2,
                column3,
                column4,
                column5,
                column6,
                column7,
                column8
            ]
        );
 
        }
        csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
         /* add the column delimiter as comma(,) and each row splitted by new line character (\n) */
        rows.forEach(function(rowArray){
            row = rowArray.join(",");
            csvContent += row + "\r\n";
        });
 
        /* create a hidden <a> DOM node and set its download attribute */
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", "Report.csv");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
         /* download the data file named "Stock_Price_Report.csv" */
        link.click();
}
```

This is when I download the excel file, look at the date output:
[image: This is when I download the excel file, look at the date output]

Comment: Your date values is too wide for column in Excel.
https://superuser.com/questions/65556/excel-displays-for-long-text-whats-wrong

Comment: What happens if you widen the date column in Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ooh I didn't even think about widening the date column, but yeah I can see it now. Thank you so much!! Appreciate it

Comment: @somename thank you so much, but do you happen to know how to automatically adjust it so that the date can fit the column

Comment: @AimanHaziq I don\`t know. This question doesn\`t belong to stackoverflow. You can not change excel spreadsheet properties with javascript when importing data as csv. Ask on another sub (superuser). If you want to control Excel look from javascript, you need to create excel file in js code. There is many libraries to help you with that ([exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)).

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the size of the column `date`

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P88WT.png)